# How to make work overflow auto with enclose div

Tags: html, css, extjs

I have the following generated structure with ExtJS 2.3, but it doesn't matter I think. I want to notice what `overflow: auto` automaticly adds to the `div.body`. Why the `div.body` with `overflow: auto` doesn't fit parents height? How to enable it? I want to enable `div.body` scrolling. Please help.

```css
div.first {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border: #f00 solid 1px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
div > div.body {
    overflow: auto;
    border: #0f0 solid 1px;
}
div > div.body > div {
    overflow: hidden;
    border: #00f solid 1px;
}
div > div.body > div > div {
    overflow: hidden;
    border: #ff0 solid 1px;
    line-height: 1.5em;
}
```

```html
<div class="first">
  <div class="header">Some header</div>
  <div class="body">
    <div>
      <div>
        test<br />
        test<br />
        test<br />
        test<br />
        test<br />
        test<br />
        test<br />
        test<br />
        test<br />
        test<br />
        test<br />
        test
      </div>
    </div>    
  </div>    
</div>
```

Comment: `overflow` property on an element requires a `height` to be set on that element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.
lets explain this with my little know english.
Here first div width is fixed. but remaining are auto so the browser calculates it.

first sets to 200px;
body try to fit within it and its child fits in but the height of the children cross the height of body div. so add some height to body div. so that child's will be calculated

```css
div.first {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border: #f00 solid 1px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
div > div.body {
    overflow: auto;
    border: #0f0 solid 1px;
  height: 90%;
}
div > div.body > div {
    overflow: hidden;
    border: #00f solid 1px;
}
div > div.body > div > div {
    overflow: hidden;
    border: #ff0 solid 1px;
    line-height: 1.5em;
}
```

```html
<div class="first">
  <div class="header">Some header</div>
  <div class="body">
    <div>
      <div>
        test1<br />
        test<br />
        test<br />
        test<br />
        test<br />
        test<br />
        test<br />
        test<br />
        test<br />
        test<br />
        test<br />
        test11
      </div>
    </div>    
  </div>    
</div>
```

Comment: try to open it with Chrome. In FF it's all ok, I'm agree.

Answer (score -1):

Remove height from `div.first` and add to `div > div.body`.

---

```css
div.first {
width: 200px;
border: #f00 solid 1px;
overflow: hidden;
}
div > div.body {
height: 200px;
overflow: auto;
border: #0f0 solid 1px;
}
div > div.body > div {
overflow: hidden;
border: #00f solid 1px;
}
div > div.body > div > div {
overflow: hidden;
border: #ff0 solid 1px;
line-height: 1.5em;
}
```

```html
<div class="first">
  <div class="header">Some header</div>
  <div class="body">
<div>
  <div>
    test<br />
    test<br />
    test<br />
    test<br />
    test<br />
    test<br />
    test<br />
    test<br />
    test<br />
    test<br />
    test<br />
    test
  </div>
</div>    
  </div>    
</div>
```

Comment: This is a bad idea, cause I have two containers inside .first

Comment: Give some height to the same div also which has `overflow: auto;`.